# Putting a years schedule together (based on Mthly waves) and need to know the formula that if a task falls on a weekend, it moves to weekday

Tags: excel, excel-formula, scheduled-tasks, weekday, weekend

I'm putting a schedule together (1 year - 12 month waves) - I want to autopopulate as much as populate - therefore, I'll have a few key dates and then will add formula to the remaining.. i.e. +1 day, +3 days etc... However, I need to know the formula that if the formula throws up a Saturday or Sunday, I need to add a day or two so the day for the task is a working day

Haven't had any luck

Comment: Welcome to SO. You need to show us more details esp. your expected output and what you have tried so far. Reading [ask] and [repro] will help you to improve your question. Maybe this link will help you too: [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Excel can be set to start the week on Sun or Mon - so if Monday is defined as day 1, then if the day number is 6 or 7 then add 2 or 1.

Comment: `=WORKDAY(theDate-1,1)` will return what you describe.  If `theDate` is a workday, it will return the same date; if `theDate` is a Saturday or Sunday, the formula will return the next Monday.

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this by 2 sequences:
`=TOCOL(SEQUENCE(52,,44928,7)+SEQUENCE(,5,0))`

The first sequence creates `52` numbers (number of weeks) numbers starting from `44928` in steps of 7 between each value. (44928 is Excel's date representation of Monday January 2nd 2023. You could also refer to a cell that holds the start date, as long as that's a Monday). This sequence is vertical.

The second adds a horizontal sequence of `5` (days you want to show) to the first sequence.

Since your first sequence is vertical and this is horizontal, the 2nd sequence will be added to each row of the 1st sequence.
This creates a 2D array. We can use `TOCOL` to flatten the 2D array to 1D vertically, or `TOROW` to flatten horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative way of accomplishing the schedule is using <kbd>WORKDAY()</kbd> , <kbd>NETWORKDAYS()</kbd> & <kbd>SEQUENCE()</kbd> Functions:

In cell <kbd>B1</kbd> we have the `Start_Date` as `1/1/2023` while in cell <kbd>B2</kbd> the `End_Date` as `31/12/23` for the year `2023` respectively, using cell references will make it dynamic as well!

The use the following formula in some where in cell <kbd>D1</kbd> as

---

```
=WORKDAY(B1,SEQUENCE(NETWORKDAYS(B1,B2)))
```

---

- The <kbd>NETWORKDAYS()</kbd> Function returns the number of whole workdays between two dates i.e. `Start_Date` and `End_Date` which `260` for this year `2023`.

---

```
=NETWORKDAYS(B1,B2)
```

---

- Next wrap it within a <kbd>SEQUENCE()</kbd> function to return a sequence of numbers, starts from `1` and ends in `260`.

---

```
=SEQUENCE(NETWORKDAYS(B1,B2))
```

---

- Lastly, taking the <kbd>WORKDAY()</kbd> function to return the serial number of the dates after the number of specified workdays.

---

```
=WORKDAY(B1,SEQUENCE(NETWORKDAYS(B1,B2)))
```

---

[image]

---

• Formula used in .Gif to show:

```
=LET(
     α,WORKDAY(B1,SEQUENCE(NETWORKDAYS(B1,B2))),
     HSTACK(TEXT(α,"ddd"),α))
```

---

Comment: Nice. I like this better than my approach.

Comment: No both are nice approach; each have their own flavors & value!!!

Comment: Another alternative with `EDATE()` --> `=WORKDAY(B1,SEQUENCE(NETWORKDAYS(B1,EDATE(B1,12)-1)))`